# How to find coefficients in this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}) * \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}(\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!})$$

How to find coefficients until the $x^{7} $ ? It is basically sin and written in form of sums but i'm not sure how should i use this form to calculate coefficients from this factor sum. How should i precede?

Comment: It might be a good idea to have the second summation index be something other than $n$.  It is clear what you mean, but...

Comment: The Cauchy product of two series should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the equation 
$$
(1-x^2/2+x^4/24-x^6/720+\dots)(C_0+C_1x+\dots+C_7x^7+\dots)=x-x^3/6+x^5/120-x^7/5040+\dots
$$
and expand out the left side. When you collect the powers of $x$, you get
$$
C_0+C_1x+(C_2-C_0/2)x^2+(C_3-C_1/2)x^3+\dots=x-x^3/6+x^5/120-x^7/5040+\dots
$$
On the left side, I only went up to $x^3$, you will need to go up to $x^7$.

Now, since these two power series are equal, their coefficients must be equal, so you get $C_0=0$, $C_1=1$, $C_2-C_0/24=0$, $C_3-C_1/2=-1/6$, etc. Solve.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}C_nx^n=\tan(x)$$

and $C_0=C_2=C_4=C_6=0$.